# How to use an header array in cpp?

Tags: c++, arrays, header

Header file:

```
class Student
{

public:
    int A[30];
//...
};
```

.cpp file:

```
// ...
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << "Name: ";
    cin >> Name.A[i];
}
// ...
```

> Member Reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union

I wanna give out all added names in a table at. 
I'm a C++ beginner - sorry :(

Comment: Show the code that defines `Name`. Without it this code is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate an instance of your class. Then you can assign to the member variable of that class.

```
Student person;         // Create a "Student" instance
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << "Name: ";
    cin >> person.A[i]; // Assign to that Student's "A" variable
}
```